# The problem with silero tts : OSError: [WinError 6] Invalid handle

Tags: python, pytorch

Everything used to work well, but now the model error appears:

```
example_text =torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models', OSError: \[WinError 6\] Invalid handle
```

the code below:

```
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
import time



sample_rate = 48000 
speaker = 'kseniya' 
put_accent = True
put_yo = True
language = 'ru'
model_id = 'v4_ru'
device = torch.device('cpu')

model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                     model='silero_tts',
                                     language=language,
                                     speaker=model_id)
model.to(device) 


def va_speak(what: str):
    audio = model.apply_tts(text=what+"..",
                            speaker=speaker,
                            sample_rate=sample_rate,
                            put_accent=put_accent,
                            put_yo=put_yo)

    sd.play(audio, sample_rate * 1.05)
    time.sleep((len(audio) / sample_rate) + 0.5)
    sd.stop()

# sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
# time.sleep(len(audio) / sample_rate)
# sd.stop()
```

I tried to reinstall `torch`, `silero`, `torchaudio`, `numpy` and others, nothing helped.Please help me.